# Stop processing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is triggered to execute when the status of a sales order changes. The procedure inserts a row into a table using the Sales Order Number as the key.

My problem is that I need to stop the procedure from executing a second (or third) time if someone goes back and modifies the sales order for some reason. I've tried a few different things but nothing has worked. Here is my latest code using `NOT EXISTS`. It works just as intended on the first insert but fails if I modify the Sales Order because it's trying to insert a duplicate record into the AECStarCustom Table. Suggestions?

I may not be using `NOT EXISTS` correctly. This is my first time using it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PostStarshipFreight 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SalesOrder varchar(30);
    DECLARE @InternalID int;
    DECLARE @OrderStatus varchar(1);

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 @SalesOrder 
                   FROM AECStarCustom 
                   WHERE AECStarCustom.SalesOrder = @SalesOrder)
    BEGIN
        SET @InternalID = (SELECT TOP 1 ShipmentID 
                           FROM StarShip..ShipmentOrder 
                           WHERE OrderNumber = @SalesOrder)
        INSERT INTO TEST_AllenEng.dbo.AECStarCustom (InternalID, SalesOrder, BOLNumber, OrderNumber, SCAC, ProcessDateTime, ProNumber, DeliveryCharge, MasterTrackingID, TotalPackQty, FreightCharge)  
            SELECT
                o.ShipmentID, 
                OrderNumber AS 'SalesOrder', s.BOLNumber, o.OrderNumber, 
                c.SCAC, s.ProcessDateTime, ProNumber,
                s.DeliveryCharge, s.MasterTrackingID, o.TotalPackQty, 
                o.FreightCharge
            FROM 
                Starship.dbo.ShipmentOrder AS o
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                Starship.dbo.Shipment AS s ON s.InternalID = o.ShipmentID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                Starship.dbo.ShipVia AS sv ON sv.InternalID = s.InternalID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                Starship.dbo.Carrier AS c ON sv.SCAC = c.SCAC 
            WHERE
                OrderNumber = @SalesOrder;
    END
```

Comment: I believe it could/should be: `If Not Exists(SELECT 1 FROM AECStarCustom WHERE AECStarCustom.SalesOrder = @SalesOrder)`. As soon as there is match the query will eval to false. You should also add a unique constraint on this column if the value must always be unique. `create unique nonclustered index [index name] on AECStarCustom (SalesOrder asc)`

Comment: Ummm you need to have an inbound parameter. The way you have this coded the SalesOrder variable will never be anything other than NULL. You probably should probably make that a parameter that you would pass when you call this.

Comment: I do have an inbound parameter for the @SalesOrder set on the vbScript used to call the procedure, but maybe I need this statement to check for the record before I call the procedure rather than inside the procedure?

Comment: @KarenD Yes, you need to add a parameter to your procedure and then implement that in your application code. As it is now, `@SalesOrder` is a local variable in your procedure - your app code cannot set it. Since the variable is never set to anything, the not exists clause always returns true.

Comment: And one more comment. Do not use 3-part names without a very, VERY, good reason. A 3-part name creates a dependency on a specific database within your instance. This increases the work needed to move your system from instance to instance and to create multiple environments (e.g., development, QA, support). If the expectation is that the procedure and the table are in the same database, then use 2 part names only (schema.table).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, SMor. I made a choice to do it in this case for a specific reason but wouldn't normally. Edited to say that once I'm out of testing I will resolve it.